# Exponentially decayed weight lattice path

Tags: mathematical-physics, integer-lattices

Consider a 4 dimensional lattice with spacing $\Delta$. Want to get expression of

$$\sum_\text{all paths} e^{-k(\Delta) L} $$
in the limit of $\Delta \rightarrow 0$

where $L$ is the number of "links" in one path. k depends on spacing.

I don't know how to start.

Comment: I'm interested in understanding the question. What exactly are $\Delta$, $k$ and $L$?

Comment: @runway44 k is a positive real number it can depends on spacing, the delta is spacing. L is the steps.

Comment: I am not that familiar with lattices. Does having a spacing of $\Delta$ mean there is a basis for the lattice consisting of vectors with magnitude $\Delta$? (This would mean all the adjacent "nodes" or hyperplanes are all $\Delta$ apart.) I take it $k(\cdot)$ is just some somewhat arbitrary function. Aren't there infinitely many paths with a given number $L$ of steps? Or are you only summing over paths starting at the origin, say?

Answer (score 0):

The quantity in the question is
$$
\sum_{\rm all\ paths}e^{-k(\Delta)L}=\sum_{L=0}^{\infty}
e^{-k(\Delta)L}2^{4L}=\frac{1}{1-16e^{-k(\Delta)}}\ .
$$
At each step one has $2^4$ choices for a direction to go, so the number of paths of length $L$, say all starting from the origin, is $2^{4L}$.
For the limit $\Delta\rightarrow 0$, one would need to know something about $k$ as a function of $\Delta$.